# HTTP::OAI::Harvester problem

Tags: apt

Specifications:

- Dell Latitude E6420
- Ubuntu version 20.04.02 LTS
- Perl version 5, version 30

Installed `libhttp-oai-perl` with `apt-get install`.

After trying to use module HTTP::OAI::Harvester with the script located in *Synopsis section* of this [article](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/man3/HTTP::OAI::Harvester.3pm.html#author):

```
           use HTTP::OAI;

           my $h = new HTTP::OAI::Harvester(baseURL=>'http://arXiv.org/oai2');
           my $response = $h->repository($h->Identify)
           if( $response->is_error ) {
                   print "Error requesting Identify:\n",
                           $response->code . " " . $response->message, "\n";
                   exit;
           }

           # Note: repositoryVersion will always be 2.0, $r->version returns
           # the actual version the repository is running
           print "Repository supports protocol version ", $response->version, "\n";

           # Version 1.x repositories don't support metadataPrefix,
           # but OAI-PERL will drop the prefix automatically
           # if an Identify was requested first (as above)
           $response = $h->ListIdentifiers(
                   metadataPrefix=>'oai_dc',
                   from=>'2001-02-03',
                   until=>'2001-04-10'
           );

           if( $response->is_error ) {
                   die("Error harvesting: " . $response->message . "\n");
           }

           print "responseDate => ", $response->responseDate, "\n",
                   "requestURL => ", $response->requestURL, "\n";

           while( my $id = $response->next ) {
                   print "identifier => ", $id->identifier;
                   # Only available from OAI 2.0 repositories
                   print " (", $id->datestamp, ")" if $id->datestamp;
                   print " (", $id->status, ")" if $id->status;
                   print "\n";
                   # Only available from OAI 2.0 repositories
                   for( $id->setSpec ) {
                           print "\t", $_, "\n";
                   }
           }

           # Using a handler
           $response = $h->ListRecords(
                   metadataPrefix=>'oai_dc',
                   handlers=>{metadata=>'HTTP::OAI::Metadata::OAI_DC'},
           );
           while( my $rec = $response->next ) {
                   print $rec->identifier, "\t",
                           $rec->datestamp, "\n",
                           $rec->metadata, "\n";
                   print join(',', @{$rec->metadata->dc->{'title'}}), "\n";
           }
           if( $rec->is_error ) {
                   die $response->message;
           }

           # Offline parsing
           $I = HTTP::OAI::Identify->new();
           $I->parse_string($content);
           $I->parse_file($fh);
```

I got an error message:

```
Can't locate object method "is_error" via package "HTTP::OAI::Identify" at ./test.pl line 7.
```

How to proceed to make the script work?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I do not see a question here.

Comment: Sorry, the question is what to do - obviously about the installation - to be able to make the script work without error.

Answer (score 0):

After contacting patrick.hochstenbach@ugent.be who maintains the package now instead of Tim Brody, some changes are necessary to the above mentioned example.

One modification of which I am uncertain whether it is really necessary was to add

```
use HTTP::OAI::Metadata::OAI_DC;
```

The main modification, however, is that instead of the "next"-method the callback-method is to be used. The modified code looks as

```
# Using a handler
$response = $h->ListRecords(
   metadataPrefix=>'oai_dc',
   handlers=>{metadata=>'HTTP::OAI::Metadata::OAI_DC'},
   onRecord=>sub {
     my $rec = shift;

     printf"%s\t%s\t%s\n"
          , $rec->identifier
          , $rec->datestamp
          , join(',', @{$rec->metadata->dc->{'title'}});
   }
);
```